# Static HTML menu

Tags: html, menu

Instead of the usual drop down menus, I need a static menu where users can toggle the hidden/visible state and the UI should remember the state.

The menu is on the left and should look like this:

```
  Link
> Menu
v Open Menu
    Sub Menu
```

That means going back and forth in the browser history should restore the menu state as it was when the page was left. Changes in the menu should not register in the browser history, only clicks on actual links should.

Comment: And you want it in JavaScript? Any libraries available?

Comment: It absolutely positively *has* to be static?  I think the only way to do what you're describing is to save menu information in a cookie and use javascript to recreate it using this information.

Comment: There is no way to do this without JavaScript.

Comment: All fields are open. If you say "Use this 2.5MB JS library", it's an option. Right now, I need a set of possible solutions. After that, I will make an educated decision.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can call that as a "tree view".

In order to achieve a tree view-like Web control in client-side you need JavaScript because raw (X)HTML and CSS has nothing to do with that.

If you've a chance of using a JavaScript library, you'd like to know jQuery has many plugins accomplishing such task. Look for them in Google and you'll find some like this:

- http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/

The other topic about state management, I believe you'll need to taylor your own solution, and it seems you'll have two options:

- **Client-side**: Using cookies you can store some JSON representing tree view's hierarchy and marking each level and item with boolean values so you can iterate this tree and recover state across page refreshes and postbacks.
- **Server-side**: Hardly I'll have a chance for suggesting a concrete solution, because I don't know which server technology you're currently using in your project, but you'll need to mimic client-side solution in your server logic, by storing such hierarchy in some session or view state management and send such JSON of client-side solution, but from server, and execute some client state JavaScript recovery function.

Comment: Interesting solution. I like it.

Comment: Thanks, if you need some other detail feel free to comment out and I'll try to update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish very simply tree menu with JavaScript, try this code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample HTML Tree Menu</title>
<style type="text/css">
a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  _display: inline;
}
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">
//<![CDATA[
function treeMenu(treeName) {
  branch = document.getElementById(treeName + "_branch").style;
  icon = document.getElementById(treeName + "_icon")
  if(branch.display == 'none') {
    branch.display = "block";
    icon.innerHTML = "v";
  } else {
    branch.display = "none";
    icon.innerHTML = ">";
  }
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javaScript:treeMenu('menu1')"><div id="menu1_icon">&gt;</div> Menu 1</a><br/>
<div id="menu1_branch" style="display:none">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+ Sub Menu 1<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+ Sub Menu 2<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+ Sub Menu 3<br/>
</div>
<A href="javaScript:treeMenu('menu2')"><div id="menu2_icon">&gt;</div> Menu 2</a><br/>
<div id="menu2_branch" style="display:none">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+ Sub Menu 1<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+ Sub Menu 2<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+ Sub Menu 3<br/>
</div>
<A href="javaScript:treeMenu('menu3')"><div id="menu3_icon">&gt;</div> Menu 3</a><br/>
<div id="menu3_branch" style="display:none">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+ Sub Menu 1<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+ Sub Menu 2<br/>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+ Sub Menu 3<br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```